# Bluetooth scan does not find any bluetooth device

Tags: drivers, laptop, bluetooth

I am running Linux Mint 17.2 64bit on a Acer Aspire-VN7-791G. Bluetooth seems to be working - at least I can turn it on - but when scanning for other devices nothing is found.

lspci returns the following

```
user@user-Aspire-VN7-791G ~ $ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:003e] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0804]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1692] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:091d]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
```

lsusb output

```
user@user-Aspire-VN7-791G ~ $ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:2970 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04ca:3011 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Also my kernel version is `4.2.0-18-generic` because I upgraded it in order to get the WiFi working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop (VN7-591G-77FS) and I'm also running mint 17.2. You need to do the followings:

1) download the latest kernel backports

https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/20/

2) unzip the archive and then in the file drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c find the following lines

```
/* QCA ROME chipset */
{ USB_DEVICE(0x0cf3, 0xe007), .driver_info = BTUSB_QCA_ROME },
{ USB_DEVICE(0x0cf3, 0xe300), .driver_info = BTUSB_QCA_ROME },
{ USB_DEVICE(0x0cf3, 0xe360), .driver_info = BTUSB_QCA_ROME },
```

and add the following below them

```
{ USB_DEVICE(0x04ca, 0x3011), .driver_info = BTUSB_QCA_ROME },
```

3) compile, install and reboot
if bluetooth doesn't work then you probably missing the required firmware which should be mentioned in some error message in dmesg. Something like

dmesg | grep -i bluetooth

should bring it up

EDIT: I just saw that you have upgraded your kernel. In that case you don't need the backports. Just find the relevant file in the kernel tree and edit it there. 
In my case I preffered the backports solution for the wifi as well ;)

Comment: Thanks, which file exactly are you talking about and where can I find it in the kernel tree?

Comment: drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Asus Aspire V 13

The BT device is Atheros.. but works with ROME setup so I added the following line to btusb.c: (then compiled as module, installed as module and loaded)

```
{ USB_DEVICE(0x04ca, 0x3011), .driver_info = BTUSB_QCA_ROME },
```

My lsusb is:

```
lsusb
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04ca:3011 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 0461:0010 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP PR1101U / Primax PMX-KPR1101U Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 03f0:094a Hewlett-Packard Optical Mouse [672662-001]
Bus 003 Device 024: ID 0b95:772b ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772B
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I submitted a bug report: [Bluetooth 04ca:3011 [Asus Aspire V3-371] doesn't work | bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1535802)

STEP by STEP what I did (assuming you did not download the whole kernel source and do not intend to):

1. downloaded the btusb.c (my kernel is 4.2, so that I got from [Linux source code: drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c (v4.2) | Bootlin](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?v=4.2)), and the 3 include headers: btbcm.h btintel.h btrtl.h (I striped the line numbering with the following command: `sed -e 's/ *[0-9]* //' btusb.txt > btusb.c` - where the txt is what you downloaded)
2. created a Makefile using `nano Makefile` with the following content:

   ```
   obj-m := btusb.o
   KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
   PWD := $(shell pwd)
   default:
   $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
   ```
3. Edited the downloaded btusb.c (actually added the above mentioned line)
4. Compiled with `make` command.
5. Installed the created module (btusb.ko) with
   `sudo make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r) M=$(pwd) modules_install`
   command
6. Ran `sudo depmod -a`
7. Removed the "old" btusb `sudo rmmod btusb`
8. Installed what I made as `sudo modprobe btusb`

Comment: For ur Makefile, I am getting

make
Makefile:5: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: Sorry for very late answer, likely you found the error few mins after your post (you need a REAL tab character before line 5) - which was likely not copied here.
In any way all above mentioned tinkering is not needed for a relative new kernel, because devs inserted that device - in the recognised list by default.